# Java Robot not working at all with java 8

Tags: java, java-8, netbeans-8, awtrobot

I was wondering if anyone else if having difficulties getting Java Robot to work. Basically I've come back to an application that I haven't worked on in a while and none of my Robot commands are working the way they should.

```
try{
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

this is an example of some simple code I'm trying to execute to press the a key and see if it's running correctly(basically I just click on notepad and see if A is shown it use to work). The only thing that is sometimes working in my current project is the mouse movement but as soon as I make an action that calls any key or mouse press that stops working too. The version of jdk I am using is 8u92 with Netbeans 8.1. Here is the example of my main key pressing class

```
public abstract class AButtonDownUpExecute {
protected Robot rob;
public AButtonDownUpExecute(){
}

protected abstract void actionKeyDown();
protected abstract void actionKeyUp();

public void executeKeyDown() throws AWTException{
    prepareRob();
    actionKeyDown();
}

private void prepareRob() throws AWTException{
    if(rob == null){
        rob = new Robot();
    }
}

public void executeKeyUp() throws AWTException{
    prepareRob();
    actionKeyUp();
}}
```

Button down simple key

```
public class ButtonDownUpSimpleKey extends AButtonDownUpExecute{
public int keyCode;

public ButtonDownUpSimpleKey(int keyCode){
    this.keyCode = keyCode;
}

@Override
protected void actionKeyDown() {
    System.out.println("keyDown: " + keyCode);
    rob.keyPress(keyCode);   
}

@Override
protected void actionKeyUp() {
    System.out.println("keyUp: " + keyCode);
    rob.keyRelease(keyCode);}}
```

And finally how the MouseMove has been implemented which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

```
public abstract class AMouseMoveExecute {
protected Robot rob;
protected String axis;

public AMouseMoveExecute(String axis){
    this.axis = axis;
}

protected abstract void actionExecute(double amount);

public void Execute(double amount) throws AWTException{
    if(rob == null){
        rob = new Robot();
    }
    actionExecute(amount);
}}
```

Mouse Move Simple

```
public class MouseMoveSimple extends AMouseMoveExecute{
private int multiplier;

public MouseMoveSimple(String axis){
    super(axis);
    multiplier = 100;
}

@Override
protected void actionExecute(double amount) {
    PointerInfo currentMouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point location = currentMouseLocation.getLocation();
    if(axis.equals("x")){
        rob.mouseMove(location.x + (int)(amount * multiplier), location.y);
    }else if(axis.equals("y")){
        rob.mouseMove(location.x, location.y + ((int) (amount * multiplier)));
    }
}}
```

I have console outputs in my main project for the exceptions and no exception is occurring.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problems. Neither `javac` nor `JDT` shows such behaviour. I'm also running `JDK 1.8.0_92`.

Comment: Can you provide a *complete* example?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my computer at home as I've just run the program at my computer at work and it seems to work fine.